# SharePoint Online managed metadata column

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, managed-metadata

I have a managed metadata column called 'year' - 2021, 2022, 2023 etc. This is in a SharePoint Online list.

It was working ok until around 3 days ago.

when i 'filter by' column, i now see the following

[image]

Any idea why i no longer see just, 2021, 2022, 2023?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be including the term ID along with the term itself. If you're using out-of-the-box functionality, then I would recommend contacting Microsoft support as this would be a bug only they could resolve.

Comment: Many thanks Cullum, we logged a ticket with Microsoft support last night.

Comment: Great, remember to upvote or mark this as the answer so that the question is seen as "answered".